# CSS not working in HTML application

Tags: html, css, hta

I am working on a HTML application, and I am trying to style an info panel. Here is the CSS code I have so far:

```
#info_panel {
    width:900px;
    height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:brown;
    border-bottom-left-radius:25px;  
    border-bottom-right-radius:25px; 
    border-top-left-radius:25px;  
    border-top-right-radius:25px;
}
```

I do not have a problem with the first four lines. The problem arises with the border radius properties. I noticed that the shadow property does not work either. I know that this code would normally work in a web browser, but this being an *application*, there seems to be a problem. Unfortunately, there is very little documentation on this subject. I would include a fiddle, but of course I could not because it would be running in a web browser. Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: can't help you, since you don't mention which rendering engine/platform you're doing this on. an answer for (say) WinPhone 8 would be useless if it turns out you're on iOS.

Comment: Do you know if hta supports border-radius?

Comment: `box-shadow` gives you a shadow `border-radius` rounds the corners You have not used any shadow property that is why it does not show

Comment: I have no idea. I searched it, but like I said, there is _very_ little help online for this subject.

Comment: @Andrew I did not include it in the code, but I did try it, and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To really run HTA with IE9 you need to set document type and a `x-ua compatible` `meta` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9"/>
....
```

Notice the order, there shouldn't be any `style`, `script` or `link` tags before `meta`.

There also seems to be a bug in IE9. Radius is not rendered, when assigned it to a `fieldset` element which has a `legend` element too. Without `legend` borders are rounded.

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather, your HTA is essentially running on Internet Explorer's rendering engine.  Only IE9 and IE10 support the `border-radius` property.  Older IEs will not show rounded corners or box shadows. Do you have IE8 installed?

If you need these style features for the older IE rendering, then look into CSS3 PIE: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I am using IE9. According to CSS3 PIE, not even IE9 renders the 'border-radius' property

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius -- this is a helpful resource for which CSS3 and HTML5 features are supported for different browsers. It says that IE9 should support 'border-radius', but regardless that does not explain why it is not working for you.  Perhaps your HTA is not using IE9 but IE8 still.

Comment: How do I tell if that is happening, and if it is, how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure because I've never made an HTA.  However, it seems like using CSS3 PIE is a good option. Otherwise you may need to have your rounded corners and box shadows be an image instead of CSS.

Comment: .hta is an old format introduced in IE5, kind of not that reliable + security concerns regarding file system access. If you are looking to simply wrap up an HTML application in an executable (.msi, so only windows), have a look at [TideSDK Developer](http://www.tidesdk.org/). It's very simple to do and is a webkit-based wrapper! If you need more advanced options, (but this is really more complicated stuff, you can look up Titanium Studio. Note: Both of these are used to build **hybrid applications**.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious as to why you are using the longhand version to specify the border radius. Have you tried the universal shorthand?

```
-moz-border-radius:25px; 
-webkit-border-radius:25px; 
border-radius:25px;
```

This the box shadow code:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Comment: I suppose I use the longhand version because it seems like cleaner programing, plus I sometimes use different values for different corners.